# Как стилизовать метку в API Яндекс.Карт?

Tags: битрикс, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, как стилизовать силами собственного API метку яндекс карты, в компоненте map.yandex.view.

Если я все правильно понимаю в папке шаблона лежит файл script.js 
в котором функция *window.BX_YMapAddPlacemark* создает эту самую метку.

```js
var obPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
     [arPlacemark.LAT, arPlacemark.LON],
   props,
   {
    preset: 'islands#darkGreenDotIcon',
    balloonCloseButton: true
   }
  );
```

Соответственно ключ **preset** указывает на предустановленный стиль метки.
Однако метка отображается с стилем по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1):

Надо создать свой макет через `ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass` и передать его в опцию `iconLayout`.

Посмотрите на пример [Задание фигуры активной области HTML макету метки](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape).